# Merging 2 Data Frames in R fully

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames as seen below:

DF1:

```
ID  ITEM1   ITEM2
1001    1   1
1002    1   1
1003        1
1004    1   
1005    1   1
```

DF2:

```
ID  ITEM3
1001    1
1002    1
```

How do I merge both data frames to get the result:

```
ID  ITEM1   ITEM2   ITEM3
1001    1   1         1
1002    1   1         1
1003        1         
1004    1       
1005    1   1
```

Answer (score 5):

You have several ways to perform a full join. Non matching keys will have `NA`s

## Base R

```r
merge(df1, df2, all=TRUE)
```

This is also valid for a `data.table` object

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% full_join(df2)
```